# Discord bot in Python - no commands are working

Tags: python, discord, command, bots

I want to create a bot that will respond to commands with arguments. I have gotten it to respond to strings in messages, but when i try to make commands working, the bot seems not to react at all. I have studied the documentation, put a lot of effor into trying to find the answer on the internet, but no help. My code can be the exact same as someone else's on the internet, but the bot never responds, while still responding to messages. I wonder if there's something really basic that I'm missing about how the commands are supposed to work.

I have imported the right library, I use the exact same syntax many people are sharing on the internet, yet the commands just don't do anything. I use replit.com which is a browser IDE.

This snippet of code is like half the code from the bot, he's quite dumb so far. Everything i tried other than commands has worked so far. I usually also don't work with Python, but i just followed the syntax i saw in tutorials to not make mistakes. When i run this, the bot logs in successfully, then if i send !tst  the bot just doesn't do anything.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(name='tst')
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.send('testt')
```

I mainly used this tutorial: https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#how-to-make-a-discord-bot-in-python
Also the library documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

#### Based on the full code:

You shouldn't use both `discord.Client` and `commands.Bot`, because you are defining two different bots, but run only one of them. `commands.Bot` extends the `discord.Client`. Think about `commands.Bot` as a subclass of `discord.Client`. Everywhere where you've used `client` before, now you can use `bot`.

The code you posted would run correctly like this:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(name='tst')
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.send('testt')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print ('Successful login as {0.user}'.format(bot)) 

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

#### Original answer:

(it might be a solution to someone else looking for it)

Are you using the `on_message` event? That prevents the command processor from getting the messages. You have to call the command processor manually, like so:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Do your stuff
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) you should call this function when you override the on_message event.

> By default, this coroutine is called inside the on_message() event. If you choose to override the on_message() event, then you should invoke this coroutine as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(name='tst')
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.send('testt')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print ('Successful login as {0.user}'.format(client)) 

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I didn't want to post the whole thing, but it's really nothing special so here it goes. for a moment i thought that might be the solution, but even if i clear it of all message related code, it still does nothing. Could it be conflicting with the on_ready message? That one just goes to the console on the IDE website..

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the Community! You shouldn't post this as an answer, instead you can edit your original question to add more information. I edited my answer to add a possible solution for you based on your code.